# Proving that a model exhibits either a first or second order phase transition

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics

**Motivating example:**
Take the (wired) random cluster model $\phi^1_{p,q}$ with parameter $q$ (see  http://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00520 for an introduction).
It is now known on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that it has a critical point (for example in the sense that the free energy is not analytic or equivalently in the sense that $ \phi^1_{p,q}( 0 \leftrightarrow \infty) $ changes from $0$ to a nonzero value) exactly at $p_c(q) = \frac{ \sqrt{q}}{1+ \sqrt{q}}$.
Further, it has been proven that the phase transition is second order (i.e. the free energy is $C^1$ but not $C^2$ or equivalently $\phi^1_{p_c(q),q}(0 \leftrightarrow \infty) = 0$ for $ 1 \leq q \leq 4$ and first order for $q > 4$ (meaning that the free energy is not differentiable at $p_c$ or equivalently $\phi^1_{p_c(q),q}(0 \leftrightarrow \infty) > 0$. Further,  it is known that  $\phi^1_{p_c(q),q}(0 \leftrightarrow \infty) \to 0$ for $q \to 4$ which means that the quantity $\phi^1_{p_c(q),q}(0 \leftrightarrow \infty)$ is continuous in $q$.

All this is now well established, but suppose I was interested in claims like:

i) Continuity of $ q \mapsto \phi^1_{p_c(q),q}(0 \leftrightarrow \infty)$.
ii) Proving that the phase transition is *either* first or second order.
iii) Proving that the area of the first order phase transition (which now know is $ (4,\infty) $) is open.

Do you know any older references or models where statements like that is proven?

Comment: The following paper contains results related to this question: https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.07033